# Adding Score Clock to Game in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, pygame

I have my code for a game here. I have commented out the displayScore(score) call in the main function to allow the program to run. When that call is uncommented the program window closes immediately after opening.

The objective of the function displayScore is to display the game score in the top left corner. Which also needs to be displayed in the right corner for the opposing player's score.

Here is the code for the game with displayScore commented out in the main function so you can run the game and everything will work. Uncomment it to see where the problem is:

```
        ball = ballmovement(ball, ballDirX, ballDirY) 
        ballDirX, ballDirY = collisionwithedges(ball, ballDirX, ballDirY)
        score = checkscore(paddle1, ball, score, ballDirX)
        ballDirX = ballDirX * collisionwithpaddles(ball, paddle1, paddle2, ballDirX) 

        pygame.display.update() #updates the display to clear surface per the frame rate
        FRAMECLOCK.tick(FRAMERATE) #Sets the Frames of program to defined rate

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Does it give an error message when it closes? There's nothing in that method that would cause it to close otherwise. You need to include that error in your post. Also, it would be worth your time to read [mcve].

Comment: My IDE didn't even give an error message which was strange. It only said to re-open the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the line

```
displayScore(score)
```

By:

```
displayScore(str(score))
```

You are trying to use a number instead of a string to the argument of render ;) Score is an int and `BASICFONT.render((score), True, WHITE)`
 asks for score to be a string or an array of bytes :)

I found the solution only by reading the console output which was a good indication ^^

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 130, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 118, in main
    displayScore(score) 
  File "test.py", line 71, in displayScore
    resultSurf = BASICFONT.render((score), True, WHITE)
TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes
```

Comment: I added in str to displayScore, now the window doesn't even open.

Comment: Hmm.. strange; in my computer, it works. Are you using python version 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python 3

Comment: Have you added the str to the function call or to the function signature? (it should be to the function call). I ask it because I can't see why it doesn't open on your computer but not on mine ^^

Are you using an IDE? Can you access the error log (it should be accessible; it's an essential tool for debugging)

Comment: I was missing a closing bracket. It keeps a score now, but is adding score everytime the pong hits the left paddle, in addition to the right wall (which is fine). It also subtracts a point everytime the pong touches the left wall.

Comment: So is your problem closed or do you need some other help? 
If a answered your question, please mark it as solved (green V tick under the voting system) ;)